# Node JS less-middleware not auto compiling

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, less

I am using [less-middleware](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware) for my node JS express app however I am having a problem in that if I update my screen.less file, it does not recompile again. To get the file to recompile I have to delete the generated .css file and reload the site.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

**LESS Complier**

```
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // set static resource directory
    app.use(require('less-middleware')({
        // LESS CSS compiler
        src : path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        yuicompress : true
    }));
```

**Directory structure:**

```
public
    stylesheets
        _functions.less
        _normalize.less
        _params.less
        screen.less
app.js
package.json
```

Any help would be appreciated! Many thanks.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks for the response but that is related to less js not node.js less compiler.

Comment: `src : path.join(__dirname, 'public'),` should be `src : path.join(__dirname, 'public','stylesheets'),`, no?

Comment: @krasu That doesn't seem to be the way it works. The code is very similar to the solution documented on less-middleware docs - https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware#express

Also the CSS does seem to be compiling no problem, the issue is recompiling is just not happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have found out the issue and it was referenced by [less-middleware](https://github.com/emberfeather/less.js-middleware#my-less-never-recompiles-even-when-i-use-force-true).

Basically, you have to declare less middleware before you declare the static resource location. So my new, working code is now as below

```
    app.use(require('less-middleware')({
        // LESS CSS compiler
        src : path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        yuicompress : true
    }));
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // set static resource directory
```